# How to upload and retrieve data under a specific user in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I'm totally a beginner with api consumption i'm creating a app where user will login with credentials which are preset in database now after login user can upload his profile photo and update profile details finally on submit click i need to fetch all data related to that particular user and display it.
How can i implement this with retrofit?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to view these [awesome Retrofit tutorial set](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) before you begin your implementation. The series contains all the things you need. For e.g.

1. Authentication: [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit)
2. Profile Image Upload: [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server)
3. Sending requests and reading responses: [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests)